# uencode -signal processing matlab

Tags: matlab, signals

i need to quantize and encode an input signal using matlab so i will use uencode function . The problem is that i am confused about its process , the description says that it quantize and encode the input as integer and then he has displayed an example :

```
u = -1:0.01:1;
y = uencode(u,3);
plot(u,y,'.')
```

The output is just integers , can somebody just explain what this integers exactly are ?? and if i need  the binary codes of the input u what i must do to get them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uencode` takes the range of floating point numbers between -1.0 and 1.0, and maps it to the integers from 0 to (2^n)-1.

For example, with n=8, the possible integers are 0 to 255. -1.0 gets mapped to 0, +1.0 gets mapped to 255, and all decimal values in between get mapped to the closest integer.

In the code example you gave, n=3, so it is mapping to the integers 0 to 7. The plot shows horizontal lines because with so few integers available to map to, many floating point values map to the same integer.

To convert a base 10 integer to a base 2 binary string, use the function `dec2bin`.

```
>> dec2bin(5)

ans =

101

>> dec2bin(17)

ans =

10001
```

If you wanting leading zeros, say so that they are always 8 bits long, use the minimum length as a second argument:

```
>> dec2bin(5, 8)

ans =

00000101
```

Comment: Thank you  paul !

Comment: can you plese help me with this :>> x=[0.001 , 0.5 , 0.4];
>> y=uencode(x,(100000/8000))
Error using uencode>uencodeParseParams (line 76)
Number of output bits must be an integer from 2 to 32.

Error in uencode (line 30)
[u, Nbits, V, isUnsigned] = uencodeParseParams(varargin{:});
 What is wrong ?